# Routing: iis not working/standalone working - asp.net core 3.0

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I deployed rest service with controller on path /api/something.
It didnot work, i can not access that path trough iis, but it works in standalone mode. Also through iis and standalone the home route works.

Comment: Could you please tell what you mean about  works in standalone mode? Do you mean directly use donet run? Do you face any error message when you accessed the application in IIS? Do you install the asp.net core runtime for your server?

Comment: Hi Brando, I found the problem, thanks for trying to help, appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution.
Missing registration for routing service caused this.
Routing in attributes did not work through iis, but had no issues in standalone mode running just with kestrel...

Often it is great if things break consistently.